# How to set BlockSize and KeySize using AES encryption in java

Tags: java, aes, encryption

I am trying to set the BlockSize and KeySize in java encryption code.
Here is my code that works fine but how to specify the aes.BlockSize=128 and aes.KeySize=128?
I have taking reference of Aes aes = AesManaged() in .NET in which we can set the following parameter as follows

```
aes.BlockSize = 128;
aes.KeySize = 128;
CipherMode.ECB;
aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
```

In the code below I have set the following three parameters:

```
aes.Key = key
aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None
```

but I am not able to set

```
aes.BlockSize = 128
aes.KeySize = 128;
```

---

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

            byte[] keyForEncription = new byte[16];
            byte[] keyForDecription = new byte[16];
            long FixedKey = 81985526925837671L;
            long VariableKey = 744818830;

            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 8; i1++) {

                keyForEncription[i1] = (byte) (FixedKey >> (8 * i1));
                keyForEncription[i1 + 8] = (byte) (VariableKey >> (8 * i1));
            }

            short[] data = new short[96];

            data[0] = 2;
            data[1] = 0;
            data[2] = 0;
            data[3] = 0;
            data[4] = 0;
            data[5] = 6;
            data[6] = 6;
            data[7] = 81;
            data[8] = 124;
            data[9] = 23;
            data[10] = 3;

            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyForEncription, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(bos, cipher);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(cos);

            byte[] byteArray_data = new byte[data.length];

            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < data.length; i1++)
                byteArray_data[i1] = (byte) data[i1];

                dos.write(byteArray_data, 0, 16);
            dos.close();

            byte[] ENCRYPTED_DATA = bos.toByteArray();

            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 8; i1++) {

                keyForDecription[i1] = (byte) (FixedKey >> (8 * i1));
                keyForDecription[i1 + 8] = (byte) (VariableKey >> (8 * i1));
            }

            SecretKeySpec skeySpec_decryption = new SecretKeySpec(keyForDecription,
                    "AES");
            Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
            cipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec_decryption);

                    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(ENCRYPTED_DATA);
            CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(bis, cipher1);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(cis);

            byte[] DECRYPTED_DATA = new byte[byteArray_data.length];
            dis.readFully(DECRYPTED_DATA, 4, 16);
            cis.close();
```

Comment: AES is always 128 bits and only supports 128, 192, and 256 bit keys. What you're confusing it with is Rijndael, which supports more key sizes and different block sizes. Apparently .NET also confuses them (but only if it doesn't throw an exception when choosing parameters outside the AES specification, which I cannot infer from your question).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're initializing the cipher with a key of 16 bytes (128 bits), it uses that as the key size implicitly.

And regarding the block size, the [JCA specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher) says:

> AES is a 128-bit block cipher supporting keys of 128, 192, and 256 bits.

So the block size is always 128-bits.